# How to overload functions with same param types but one is nullable

Tags: kotlin

I'm trying to add two extension function to `Calendar` Class in Android to convert the specific date-time pattern to Calendar and vise versa

```
fun Calendar.fromIsoString(date: String): Calendar = this.apply {
    time = SimpleDateFormat(SERVER_DATE_PATTERN, Locale.US).parse(date)
}

fun Calendar.fromIsoString(date: String?): Calendar? {
    if (date == null) return null
    time = SimpleDateFormat(SERVER_DATE_PATTERN, Locale.US).parse(date)
    return this
}
```

But it gives me the following Error:

> Platform declaration clash: The following declarations have the same JVM signature (fromIsoString(Ljava/util/Calendar;Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/util/Calendar;)

Is it possible to have these two functions besides each other? how?

Note:
I somehow handled the problem by adding a `Unit` optional parameter to one of the functions:

```
fun Calendar.fromIsoString(date: String?, a: Unit = Unit): Calendar? {
if (date == null) return null
    time = SimpleDateFormat(SERVER_DATE_PATTERN, Locale.US).parse(date)
    return this
}
```

But I think it is tricky and not a good practice!
Is there any better solution?

Comment: I really should only keep the optional one. And in the places you are sure it is not null just call it followed by the not-null assertion operator ( !! ). No need to null check it then.

Comment: @MathijsSegers is incorrect in his comment.

Comment: @IvoBeckers that does not help him solve his issue and keep his code with the same functionality.  He can actually do what he is trying to do given the correct annotation on one of the methods.

Comment: IMHO, having the nullable function does not make sense, in a readable way it can be confusing and can imagine that in null case the function has a default value. You can extract the condition `if null then null` and put it outside, your API will be cleaner

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There is a simple solution that allows you to do this without changing your methods or the name you want to call them from Kotlin.

For Kotlin the distinction between the two methods is clear, but for the JVM it is not.  Therefore, just tell Kotlin that you want a different internal JVM name for one of the methods which will not impact Kotlin code at all.  Only Java code would see the alternative name.  For example:

```kotlin
fun Calendar.fromIsoString(date: String): Calendar = this.apply {
    // ... your code without change
}

@JvmName("fromIsoStringNullable") // <-- this solves your problem without changing the name in Kotlin
fun Calendar.fromIsoString(date: String?): Calendar? {
    // ... your code without change
}
```

voilà!  no more error!  You can call either version from Kotlin using the same name `someCalendar.fromIsoString(...)`

Other answers and comments suggesting the nullability is syntactical sugar are far from correct.  These types are written into the bytecode as extra metadata that only Kotlin will see and enforce.  But on top of that, it also adds a `@Nullable` annotation to the parameter.  In fact, all Kotlin generated function parameters have `@NotNull` and `@Nullable` annotations in the bytecode for other languages or analyzers to see and enforce if they care enough to do so.

Comment: cool, I learned something new. I was just wondering. Does this mean that the second method only gets called when it's null? and the the first method always gets called when it's not null?

Comment: Second function is called for any nullable string, the other called for any guaranteed not null string.  The value in the variable is not considered.